# How can I distinguish between an unset float and one with a value of 0?

Tags: objective-c, undefined, equality, cgfloat

I have a method that needs to do a different thing when given an unset float than a float with the value of 0. Basically, I need to check whether or not a variable has been, counting it  as set if it has a value of 0.

So, **what placeholder should I use as an unset value** (nil, NULL, NO, etc) and **how can test to see if a variable is unset** without returning true for a value of 0?

Comment: Why not NaN (say, 1.0/0.0)?  To test whether a float is NaN, it's just `num != num` (NaN is not equal to anything, even itself).

Comment: Acquiring NaN by division by zero is dangerous, as it might trap / generate a signaling NaN

Comment: Is there a better way?  I haven't messed with NaNs enough to worry about how to *intentionally* generate them.  :)  Pretty sure `NaN` wouldn't work as a float literal...

Comment: Yeah..that works.  And doesn't look as hackish :)

Comment: Why make one variable do double duty? Use a separate flag to indicate set/not set, or rethink your approach to avoid the unset state altogether.

Comment: @Caleb Here's the context. I have a class with two main properties. It has an instance method to, if only one property is set, fill in whichever property isn't (based on some math done with other values passed to this method). This works well because it lets me complete the set of properties without knowing anything about them.

Comment: I would have to agree with Caleb's suggestion. Additionally, though I do not know what you are implementing, if for any reason invoking your calculation on NaN can have a meaningful result, then checking against `nan()` removes functionality or even correctness from your application.

Comment: @Zéychin In this particular case, adding separate flags would make things a lot messier than just checking to see if a variable has been assigned. There is never any chance that math will be done on NaN; nothing happens if `isnan()` comes out true.

Comment: A funny thing about nan: Doing math with it will result in nan, and it will always compare unordered, so checks for equality (or float-almost-equality) will also fail.

Comment: How can using a separate flag make the code "a lot messier" than overloading the meaning of NaN? You need a check either way, so it's just a matter of how to write the condition. I'm sure you can make it work using NaN or some other special value, but that sure wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: @Caleb Well, the issue is that I don't know in advance which property will be defined and which one won't, so there's no good way to set a separate flag. I definitely hear you that this isn't the intended use of NaN, but I think it's the cleanest option in this particular case. Thanks for your help, I'll definitely keep it in mind :)

Comment: @NathanG. You'd use a flag for each property. Write your own setter for each property so that you can manage the flags automatically, and provide accessors for the flags, like `-isXValid` and `-isYValid`.

Comment: @Caleb how are you overloading the meaning of NaN if you use it to represent the fact that your variable is Not A Number, because you never assigned it one?

Comment: @dionadar NaN may not be a number, but it's a valid value for a float and it means that the result of some computation isn't defined. If you use it to mean "I haven't assigned a value yet" then you lose it's other meaning.

Comment: @Caleb The result of the empty computation is not defined. Therefore, an unset variable should be NaN by default under your argument.

Comment: @dionadar Perhaps NaN would be a good initial value for the variable in question (let's call it X), but X == NaN doesn't mean that X was never set. Again, you *could* give NaN that meaning, but then you have to take steps in your code to ensure that NaN can never be assigned to X. That defeats the intent of NaN in the first place which was to allow computations that give an undefined result. Otherwise you have no way to know whether NaN means "never assigned" or "undefined result."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can initialize your floats to NaN (e.g. by calling [`nan()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nan.html) or [`nanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanf.html)) and then test with [`isnan()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isnan.html) if they have been changed to hold a number. (Note that testing `myvalue == nan()` will *not* work.)

This is both rather simple (you will probably include `math.h` in any case) and conceptually sensible: Any value that is not set to a number is "not a number"...

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I got it working with `CGFloat myFloat = NAN;` and `if (isnan(myFloat)) {...}`.

Comment: Another option for your specific case would be using MAXFLOAT.

Answer (score 3):

Using a constant value to indicate the unset state often leads to errors when the variable legitimately obtains the value of that constant.

Consider using `NSNumber` to store your float.  That way it can not only be `nil`, it will default to that state.

This assumes that you only need a small number of floats.  If you need millions of them, `NSNumber` may be too slow and memory-intensive.

Comment: I need to do math with these floats, so NSNumber isn't ideal. I suppose I could temporarily convert, but that seems expensive and unnecessary. Can you expand on the dangers of using something like NaN?

Comment: The danger is if your float could end up assigned, but holding the value NaN, so that your code treats it as unassigned.  Of course, you should not blindly pass NaN into most math routines anyway.  If these values come from the user, telling them to re-type when their input resulted in NaN is also logical.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overloading these `float` properties (let's call them X and Y), create a separate `isValid` flag for each property. Initialize the flags to indicate that the floats haven't been set, and provide your own setters to manage the flags appropriately. So your code might look something like:

```
if (self.isXValid == YES) {
    self.Y = ... // assigning to Y sets isYValid to YES
}
else if (self.isYValid == YES) {
    self.X = ... // assigning to Y sets isXValid to YES
}
```

You could actually go a step further and have the setter for X also assign Y and vice versa. Or, if X and Y are so closely linked that you can calculate one based on the value of the other, you really only need one variable for both properties.